# Why does this rake task run the method twice before running the rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I wanted to create a logger to output some messages to the screen as well as the log file.  I had created a method in the rake task that I was going to pass the message to so I could output to both screen and log file, if required.  This returned argument 1 of 0 message when run.  To investigate this further I created a simple rake task below just to see what was going on.

***Task***

```
namespace :x do
  desc "test"
  task :y => :environment do
    puts "hello"
  end
  def logger
    puts "logger"
  end
end
```

Surprising, when I ran the task it would run the logger method twice before running the actual task (see output).

***Output***

```
$ rake x:y
logger
logger
hello
```

This explained my argument error because it wouldn't have any arguments passed to the logger method if it was run before the task.

My question is two fold:

1) Why does it run the method at all as it's not referenced in the task?

2) Why does it run the method twice? (I would expect once if it was going to run it but twice is just plain odd)

I'll go back to putting all the logging in the task and remove the method.  It would be useful to know why the simple example does what it does.

***EDIT***
I've done a screen dump showing the code and results below.

[image]

Comment: Your code should only output hello. Are you sure you put the exact code you ran ?

Comment: Syl, yep I've added a screen dump showing the output to the original description.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but I only get hello as an output. No idea what is happening.

Comment: I'll just have to use my work around.  I am going to check if this behaviour is consistent in other projects.  If I get to the bottom of this I'll post an answer.